# Is it possible to convert JSON Input while sending data from IOT hub to CosmosDb using Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm having JSON INPUT (Iot HUB)

```
{
    "time": 1574266369775,
    "latitude": 70.703271,
    "longitude": 25.8445082,
    "accuracy": 23.320999145507812,
    "altitude": 498.8999938964844,
    "id": "abs8d5c2ff74b5a5"
}
```

and want to store that into the cosmosDb, in particulate `key` location.

```
{
    "updatedtime": 1574345877283,
    "time": 1574347747884,
    "status": "available",
    "deviceId":"abs8d5c2ff74b5a5",
    "location": {
        "time": 1574266369775,
        "latitude": 70.703271,
        "longitude": 25.8445082,
        "accuracy": 23.320999145507812,
        "altitude": 498.8999938964844,
        "id": "abs8d5c2ff74b5a5"
     }
}
```

Is it possible? I'm able to store it into the first level but can it be store in the key of any document?

Answer (score 0):

> Stream Analytics integration with Azure Cosmos DB allows you to insert or update records in your container based on a given Document ID column. This is also referred to as an Upsert.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output) also says that it enables partial updates to the document, that is, addition of new properties or replacing an existing property is performed incrementally.

My 2 cents: try to name your output as 'location' and make sure you have the same document id when writing to the cosmos db output from your ASA job.